# Числа Фибоначчи (ошибка при вычислении первых 50 чисел)

Tags: php, числа-фибоначчи

```
function fibonacci($n)
{
    if ($n < 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fibonacci($n-1) + fibonacci($n-2);
    }
}
for ($n = 1; $n <= 16; $n++) {
    echo(fibonacci($n) . ", ");
}
echo("...\n")
```

Есть следующий код на php. Он реализует вывод на экран 16 чисел Фибоначчи. Нам необходимо вывести 50 чисел, но при замене 16 на 50 при запуске происходит ошибка и выдаются лишь 32 числа. Подскажите, что не так и как это исправить. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: И в чем, собственно, вопрос?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 50 будет ещё одна проблема - число достаточно большое (12586269025 - это 34 бита). Но в php есть специальная функция для складывания больших чисел, которые представлены в виде строк.
Да, и рекурсивный метод достаточно медленный. Вот простой способ с дополнительным массивом

```
<?php
// массив для элементов
$a = array();

// первые два - единицы    
$a[1] = '1'; // они в виде строки!
$a[2] = '1';

// а дальше - просто складываем два предыдущих
for ($i = 3; $i < 200; $i++) {
  $a[$i] = bcadd($a[$i-1], $a[$i-2]);
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 200; $i++) {
  echo($i."\t".$a[$i].", <br/>\n");
}
echo("...\n")
?>
```

до 500-го элемента выводит без каких либо проблем.

Comment: Спасибо спасибо спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 5):

вы можете сколько угодно увеличивать ввремя выполнения скрипта, проблема останется. Потому что у вас совершенно никудышный алгоритм вычисления. Чем больше аргумент вашей, функции, тем больше времени ей требуется для вычисления - количество рекурсивных обращений растет экспоненциально. Это значит, что если вы возьмете в качестве аргумента что-нибудь около ста, то рискуете не дождаться окончания выполнения функции в течение собственной жизни.

Вот вам алгоритм чуть получше (написан на C#, думаю, перевести на php проблем не составит) Здесь без рекурсии, используется обычный цикл со счетчиком:

```
    int  Fibonacci(int n) 
    {
        int i, a = 0, b = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b = a + (a = b);
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Хм...И что нам тогда делать?Более хорошего алгоритма я не нашла,а сама создать,увы не могу...Не понимаю

Comment: смотрите в ответе, дополнил

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробуем

Answer (score 3):

Вариант кода для новичков в PHP:

```
fibonacci(50);
function fibonacci($n) {
    $a = 0;
    $b = 1;
    $r = 0; // Определяем переменную с результатом
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $r = $a + $b;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $r;
        echo $r.' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fib($n)
{
    $result = [1, 1];

    for($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++ ) {
        $result[] = $result[$i-1] + $result[$i-2];
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(fib(50));
```

Answer (score -1):

Истекает максимальное время выполнения скрипта. Попробуйте увеличить его функцией [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php) или правкой php.ini (параметр `max_execution_time`).

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробуем. С правкой php.ini (параметр max_execution_time) не получалось, попробуем  функцией.