# Проблема с поиском чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: php, числа-фибоначчи

Необходимо получить число Фибоначчи большее 100. Написал такую функцию:

```
public function main(int $n): string
{
    if ($n < 0) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    $array = [0, 1];
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = $array[$i - 1] + $array[$i - 2];
    }

    return $array[$n];
}
```

Но в юнит тесте 12 = 139583862445, 99 = 121253296785055132210628998331901307849293052175954107980980734350044979474331514800545696516184354. Мб у кого есть идеи по реализации?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Числа Фибоначчи (ошибка при вычислении первых 50 чисел)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230887/%d0%a7%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-50-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb). Это слишком академическая задача. Её разжевали уже миллионы раз на любых ЯП, алгоритмы от этого не меняются.

Comment: Видел этот вопрос, но он не решает поставленную задачу. Даже при n=12 получается 144, а у меня совсем другие цифры. Да и по условию задачи нельзя использовать библиотеку BCMath.

Comment: Код там корректный, сам проверил перед тем, как отправить на дубликат.

Comment: Да и без BCMath у Вас не получится работать с большими числами, они будут неточными.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее все всего ошибка в тесте. [Я взял ваш код,](https://onlinephp.io/c/3903b) немного добавил условий, и выполнил ряд тестов(можете сами посмотреть) - все работает корректно

```
function main(int $n): int
{
    if ($n < 0) {
        //throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        return -500;
    }
    if ($n === 1) return 0;
    if ($n === 2) return 1;
    $array = [0, 1];
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = $array[$i - 1] + $array[$i - 2];   //echo $array[$i], "\n";
    }
    return $array[$n];
}

echo main(12), "\n";
echo main(11), "\n";
echo main(10), "\n";
echo main(5), "\n";
echo main(2), "\n";
echo main(1), "\n";
echo main(0), "\n";
echo main(-1), "\n";
?>
```